# Cannot concatenate string with another string retrieved by file_get_contens in PHP

Tags: php, json, string, concatenation, filereader

So I got a application printing the following log:

```
{"date":"15/09/2016", "time":"09:29:58","temp":"17.0", "humidity":"95.0" },
{"date":"15/09/2016", "time":"09:30:01","temp":"17.0", "humidity":"95.0" },
{"date":"15/09/2016", "time":"09:30:03","temp":"17.0", "humidity":"95.0" },
```

And with the help of PHP I read it and print like this which works fine:

```
<?php   
 $logFile = file_get_contents( "../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log" ); 
 echo $logFile;
?>
```

Now I want to convert this to a JSON object but if you noticed I am missing some brackets for it to be valid. I would need to remove the last comma sign and add some brackets, something like this:

```
<?php
 $logFile = file_get_contents( "../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log" ); 

 $stringLength = strlen($logFile)-2; //Get the length of the log

 $logFile = substr($logFile, 0,$stringLength); //Removes the last comma.

 $logFile = '{"log":[' . $logFile . ']}'; //Add brackets

 echo $logFile; //Print result

 $json = json_decode($logFile, true); //create JSON Object
?>
```

The problem is whenever I try to add a string to the $logFile variable, php throws an error (I don't know which unfortunatley). I can concatenate "normal" strings like 'Hello' . 'World' just fine so it has to do something with the get_file_contens method. But what I can find it should return a simple string.

My final output that I want should be this:

```
{"log":[
{"date":"15/09/2016", "time":"09:29:58","temp":"17.0","humidity":"95.0" },
{"date":"15/09/2016", "time":"09:30:01","temp":"17.0", "humidity":"95.0" },
{"date":"15/09/2016", "time":"09:30:03","temp":"17.0", "humidity":"95.0" }
]}
```

I might add that I am running this on a Apache server running on my Raspberry Pi, but I have installed PHP and some things do work so I don't think it has anything to do with that.

Comment: Why not just use `rtrim($logFile, ',')` to remove the last comma?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: which statement exactly is throwing the error?

Comment: When I am concatenating the $logFile with the brackets, that is causing errors. I don't know which error though, all chrome is saying HTTP 500, so server error which could mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of `trim` to remove the newlines, `rtrim` to get rid of the trailing commas in an `array_map` callback.
And some back and forth `json_decode` and `json_encode`

See below

```
<?php

$logLines = file('logfile.txt');

$entries = array_map("clean",$logLines);

$finalOutput = [
    'log'   => $entries
];

print json_encode($finalOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
// add the flag so the slashes in the dates won't be escaped

function clean($string){

    return json_decode(rtrim(trim($string),','),true);

}
```

This will output

```
{"log":[{"date":"15/09/2016","time":"09:29:58","temp":"17.0","humidity":"95.0"},{"date":"15/09/2016","time":"09:30:01","temp":"17.0","humidity":"95.0"},{"date":"15/09/2016","time":"09:30:03","temp":"17.0","humidity":"95.0"}]}
```

Comment: This actually worked! Thanks alot! Been at this problem now for a whole day. :)